# Why is $error[0].tostring().contains not working properly?

Tags: powershell

I have the following try-catch statement to process a DB table/dimension.  For some reason, if i turn off the (MSSQLSERVER) service on the server, the 1st if statement to capture the exception that

> Ensure that the server is running

is never touched and instead it goes to the second if condition and writes to host

> Error Processing dimension: A connection cannot be made. Ensure that
>   the server is running.

```
        try {
                Invoke-ProcessTable -DatabaseName "$DB" -Server "$server" -RefreshType "Full" -TableName "sometable" > $null

                write-host "Processing completed!"
        }
        catch{
                if($error[0].tostring().contains("Ensure that the server is running"))
                {
                    write-host "`r`nProcessing failed!`r`n(MSSQLSERVER) service is not running on $server!"
                    #$exit = 1
                }
                elseif ($error[0])
                {
                    Write-Host "Error Processing dimension: $($error[0])"
                }
        }
```

The exception message if the service is not running on the server is as follows:

> A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.

so what is wrong with `$error[0].tostring().contains("Ensure that the server is running")`

it should be outputting this:

> Processing failed!(MSSQLSERVER) service is not running on server!

Comment: Is it really necessary to cross post in 3 different forums at the same time? [MS Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eaa354a8-4880-4707-af5e-703513e2968c/why-error0tostringcontains-not-working-correctly?forum=winserverpowershell) , [Powershell.org](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/error0-tostring-contains-not-working/)  and here?

Comment: @Olaf Im in a time crunch so the more/faster help the better.

Comment: So what does `$error[0].tostring()` actually contain?

Comment: @mklement0 seems like he/she got something helpful in the technet forum. :)

Comment: @Olaf: Glad to hear it, though as of this writing the TechNet post only advises use of `Write-Host $_`, which would answer _my_ question and get us closer to the answer to _this_ question - but is obviously not a solution in itself. Wherever the right solution is discovered, it's worth also posting it here; alternatively, if it turns out there's nothing of general interest in the question, it should be deleted.